# show real time tweets on web page using search query

Tags: javascript, twitter, tweets, tweetstream

I am trying to show real time tweets by search query on a web page. I found twitter widget https://twitter.com/settings/widgets which can be used to show tweet for a given string which we have to provide when creating widget. My requirement is that search query will keep on changing in the page so I have to display tweet for that query.

Is it possible using twitter widget? I am not able to find any settings in widget, are there other JS libraries which provide this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Twitter Developer Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)

Comment: this is what i followed, but query string we have to provide when creating a widget it cant be changed i guess from the program. I replaced the query parameter in the href attribute in the code which we get after creating the widget but I was still getting the result for the query which I gave when creating the widget.